# Какой нужен падеж после слов "приговор" и "мера пресечения"?

Tags: согласование, падежи

Оставили в силе приговор кому или кого? Продлили меру пресечения кому или кого

Comment: М-Г все сказал вам. В спорных случаях словарь в помощь. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/rose/

Answer (score 1):

Имеется в виду приговор, вынесенный кому-то, в разговорной речи — "приговор кому-то". **Оставили в силе приговор (кому?) кому-то.**

**Продлили (что?) меру пресечения. Продлили (кому?) кому-то.**

Comment: а можно ссылку на правило, которое можно тут использовать?

Comment: Не думаю, что есть одно правило. Нужно определить пару связанных слов, тип связи между ними (в данном случае это управление), вспомнить или по словарям определить, каким падежом управляет главное слово. Ну, и следить за тем, чтобы фраза была осмысленной. Я не профи, есть на сайте учителя, может они еще что-то подскажут.

Answer (score 1):

Во всех этих случаях **ему** что-то "*присуждают*" (конкретный глагол меняется и даже может опускаться и только подразумеваться, а субъект воздействия "**он**" остаётся вместе со своими падежами), а именно: **ему** *выносят*, а затем *оставляют в силе* приговор, **ему** *избирают* и позже *продлевают* меру пресечения.